# Karger's algorithm: why does every vertex have degree at least the number of edges crossing a min cut?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms, minimum-cuts

I'm currently watching a video on the analysis of Krager's Algorithm, and I am confused about something.

The analysis goes as follows:

Fix a min cut $(A,B)$.

Let $k$ = # of edges crossing $(A,B)$ , these edges will be called $F$

Let $S_{i}$ be the event that an edge of $F$ is contracted in iteration $i$.

For the first iteration, 
$\Pr [S_i] = \frac{\text{# of crossing edges}}{\text{# of edges}}=\frac{k}{m}$,

where $k$ is the number of crossing edges, and $m$ is the total number of edges.

Here's where I get confused:

**Observation**: The degree of each vertex is at least k

**Reason**: Each vertex v defines a cut $\left( \{v\}, V - \{v\} \right)$

[image]

I don't really understand. The reason given for his observation doesn't make much sense to me. Why would the degree of each vertex be *at least* the number of edges crossing our min cut (A,B)?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pretty much have the answer in front of you.

For any vertex $v$, the cut $\left(\left\{v\right\},V\setminus\left\{v\right\}\right)$ has $\text{deg}(v)$ crossing edges.

If there exists a vertex $v$ with degree $<k$, then its corresponding cut has less than $k$ crossing edges, contradicting the minimality of $(A,B)$.

Comment: Wow, that's...strangely simple...